# Kubernetes deployment deletion logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have my application running in EKS cluster.I have exposed the application using Ingress- ALB load balancer controller. ALB load balancer controller has deleted recently, how to find when it got deleted.

Answer (score 2):

If you have configured the ALB-ingress controller driver to dump logs on S3. Its a place to start. This [enter link description here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v1.1/guide/ingress/annotation/#:%7E:text=enable%20access%20log%20to%20s3) guide will be a good start to understand how could it be configured.

Here is a pattern of an annotation for the ALB ingress controller that you could use for searching:

```yaml
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: access_logs.s3.enabled=true,access_logs.s3.bucket=my-access-log-bucket,access_logs.s3.prefix=my-app
```